# How to disable/apply filename rule for sonarqube

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have **Reactjs** [*with **typescript (.tsx or .ts)**+ **javascript(.js)** combination of files*] and I have below sonar configurations,

```
const lintExclusions = `**/bootstrap.js, 
                        **/bootstrap.tsx, 
                        **/AppCompnonent.js, 
                        **/AppCoponent.tsx, 
                        ...`;

const testExclusions = `src/bootstrap.js,
                        src/bootstrap.ts,
                        ...`;

scanner(
  {
    serverUrl: `localhost:4200`,
    token: `1234567`,
    options: {
      "sonar.sources": "./src",
      "sonar.exclusions": `${lintExclusions}`,
      "sonar.tests": "./src",
      "sonar.test.inclusions": "./src/**/*.test.tsx,./src/**/*.test.ts,./src/**/*.test.js ",
      "sonar.coverage.exclusions": `${testExclusions}`,
      "sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths": "coverage/lcov.info",
      "sonar.testExecutionReportPaths": "test-report.xml"
    }
  },
  () => process.exit()
);
```

---

**Code smell** issue reported by sonar,

> Rename this file to "**TimeDistanceComponent**"

**filename:**

```
src/components/time-distance.tsx
```

**file content**:

```
export default TimeDistanceComponent{
    ...
    ...
}
```

***How to disable this rule or how to tell sonarqube to accept kebab-case filename***?

Comment: Can it be that the missing component in the filename causes the issue?  --> src/components/time-distance-component.tsx

Comment: Not really. I must be able to give any name to file. eg. `time-dist.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) you can find the official documentation for disabling rules:

> **Exclude specific rules from specific files Analysis Scope > D. Issue**
>
> Exclusions > Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria
>
> You can prevent specific rules from being applied to specific files by combining one or more pairs of strings consisting of a rulekey pattern and a file path pattern.
>
> **The key for this parameter is sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria. However, because it is a multi-value property, we recommend that only be set through the UI.**

And here [you can find rules documentation](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/sonarsource/rules?languages=js&types=CODE_SMELL) where you can find rule id.